# Datatype in sql developer is opaque

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I am debugging a part of my code. I created datatype called array2D. which is a table of number_array which is table of number.

```
create or replace type NUMBER_ARR is table of NUMBER;
create or replace TYPE ARRAY2D AS TABLE OF NUMBER_ARR;
```

I compile both types for debug and after doing so i am able to see each row of the table. But not individual elements stored in it. Element's type is listed as opaque. I had this for the whole table before I compiled datatype for debug.

Comment: Where is your code where you can see rows thing and cannot see elements. `Element's type is listed as opaque.` where you see it? `I had this for the whole table`  where is the DDL of that table. More detailed info required. Next why would you compile collection data type for debug?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/dogcei

Comment: http://prntscr.com/dogcei
http://prntscr.com/dogcle
http://prntscr.com/dogctc
http://prntscr.com/dogcxk

as you can see on the last picture i cant see value in the array. And its type is opaque. Before i compiled collection data type I couldnt even "look into table". It said type: opaque on first picture allready (now is array2d). 
I hope I made it more clear now.

Comment: @Kristjan..Pics are not visible to everyone. Some places people cannot see the pics so please post in the question your code

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace type NUMBER_ARR is table of NUMBER;
/
create or replace TYPE ARRAY2D AS TABLE OF NUMBER_ARR;
/

create table t (id integer primary key, n array2d)
nested table n store as n_a(nested table column_value store as n_c);

insert into t values(1, array2d(number_arr(1,2), number_arr(3,4)));
insert into t values(2, array2d(number_arr(1,4)));
```

`Select * from t` displays:

```
ID  N
----------------------------
1   [unsupported data type]
2   [unsupported data type]
```

Now, to display the values, you have to convert each element into table and join like so:

```
select t1.id, t3.column_value value
from t t1, table(t1.column_value) t2, table(t2.column_value) t3;

ID  value
----------------
1    1
1    2
1    3
1    4
2    1
2    4
```

To display all the values per ID, you may use listagg

```
select t1.id, 
    listagg(t3.column_value, ', ')
        within group (order by t3.column_value) value
from t t1, table(t1.column_value) t2, table(t2.column_value) t3
group by t1.id;

ID  value
----------------
1    1, 2, 3, 4
2    1, 4
```

Ofcourse, it's displaying all the element of 2d array as single string of numbers.
The proper display (i.e. each array inside its own brackets like `((1,2,3,4),(4,5,6)))` is not possible as per your current type definitions.

This doesn't work:

```
select id, '(' || listagg(value, ',') 
    within group (order by value) || ')' from
(select t1.id, t2.column_value c, '(' || listagg(t3.column_value, ',')
    within group (order by t3.column_value) ||')' value
from t t1, table(t1.column_value) t2, table(t2.column_value) t3
group by t1.id, c)
group by id;
```

To make query like above work, you have to define object type and define [map and order functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjbas.htm#ADOBJ7084).

Lastly, I want to say you should stick with regular datatypes as they much more efficient.

<sub>P.S. - If there is no unique key, then you have to use `rownum` or `rowid`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for extensive answer. Really appreciate it. I'd like to ask you if you don't mind. What regular datatype would you advise me to use?

Comment: cant edit, so I'm adding another comment:
I'm used to python dictionaries/arrays. So I'd like to be able to address and change each individual cell in my 2d array.

Comment: Does the size of arrays change or it's fixed? If it changes, does it have some upper limit?

Comment: Number of rows is fixed. Number of columns does change but upper limit would be something like 200.